# Powershell help when comparing csv files

Tags: powershell

I have two csv files (a reference file and a new records file). Compare-object is just not able to help me out as the csv files, despite having overlapping data are formatted differently.

As an example: the reference file, exported from Excel, has 1000s records as such

```
"date","account","description","amount"
"1/29/2013","Chase1","Kohl's"," $(32.05)"
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target"," $(65.29)"
```

The new records file, based on csv downloads from chase or other bank website is more vanilla and looks like this

```
date,account,description,amount
1/31/2013,Chase1,Target,-65.29
```

Would someone supply some code that allows this line above in the new_records file to match with the second line in the reference file. Basically need to be able to import csv but ignore the formatting in the reference file before routing it to any comparator (such as compare-object) or custom function.

I am open to multiple intermediate files being created, or an inefficient for-loop, or using compare-object etc.

### Update

Despite all the comments I do not have a working solution. Need code to help strip out currency formatting from a csv file and compare with a raw file that does not have this formatting.

Comment: Wouldn't it help you if you remove all quotes and $() in your reference file?

Comment: What is the end goal here (other than just comparing two records)? Reporting discrepancies? Creating a new combined record set?

Comment: @MartinBrandl thanks for your comment. It'll be hard to reformat the reference file as that is an export from an excel file that I have had for 5 years. It has pivot tables and such. I use powershell to export it to csv.

Comment: I would say it would be hard to do. The one file has a negative sign to indicate the negative number and the other one wraps it in parenthesis. You would have to develop some way to parse this upon import so they match the same type.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good question. The end goal is to find just the truly new records in the new_records file and then simply add paste those into the reference file. As you can imagine, when you download bank transactions it is hard to specify cutoff dates and then dig through and figure out when you did this the last time. Best to get all that the bank is offering now, and compare with what you've already done earlier and import the rest. Thank you.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman That's why  I am asking for help - I do not know how to make powershell understand that "$(32.05)" and -32.05 are essentially the same. Powershell reads the CSVs just fine though.

Comment: PowerShell *doesn't* know that `$(32.05)` and `-32.05` are the same.  You'll have to give it some code to either _interpret_ it that way, or _change_ a value to match the other, exactly.  Look at what @MartinBrandl suggested, and consider using `Replace`?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\deleted.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\deleted2.csv" 
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property date,account,description,amount -IncludeEqual

File1
date,account,description,amount
1/31/2013,Chase1,Target,-65.29
1/31/2013,Chase1,Target,-32.05

File2
date, account , description , amount 
 1/29/2013 , Chase1 , Kohl's ,  $(32.05) 
 1/31/2013 , Chase1 , Target ,  $(65.29)
```

Got this

[image]

Comment: Here's what I got when I execute this. Basically the records are shown as different. "date","account","description","amount","SideIndicator"
"1/29/2013","Chase1","Kohl's","$(32.05)","=>"
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target","$(65.29)","=>"
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target","-65.29","<="
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target","-32.05","<="

Comment: `"date","account","description","amount","SideIndicator"
"1/29/2013","Chase1","Kohl's","$(32.05)","=>"
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target","$(65.29)","=>"
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target","-65.29","<=" 
"1/31/2013","Chase1","Target","-32.05","<="`

Comment: Guys I still don't have a working solution. Can anyone provide. Thank you.